Canvas2D performance differences depending on browser?
I am using Adobe Animate to create content for my HTML5 project.
Adobe Animate uses Createjs to create HTML5 content (Canvas2D based).
I tested it on several mobile devices to make sure it runs smoothly on mobile browsers, and I found something strange.
Chrome 106 is "much" better than Chrome's higher versions (e.g. 126), regardless of browser and device capabilities.
I am not saying Chrome 106 is perfect, but I don't understand why the latest version of Chrome is slower.
regardless of my optimizations, the browser is making my content run slower, and it is annoying that it is the latest version of the browser.
Does anyone know why this is?
(Please understand that this was written using a translator.)
Chrome Ver 126
Chrome ver 106
Hardware acceleration is turned on in both versions of Chrome (106, 126).
As you can see, there are occasional stutters in 126, which seems to be the cause of the frame drops, but I couldn't analyze the browser console for the huge number of functions that Createjs outputs.
If there's any additional information I should provide, please let me know.
